# Why do the humans in Solaris keep trying to hide the "visitors"?

Tags: novel, character-motivation, solaris

In the novel *Solaris*, there are 8 main entities on the space station Solaris: 3 living humans (Kris, Snow, Sartorius), 1 dead human, and 4 visitors.

At around the middle of chapter 6, it has become public knowledge among the living humans that every human has a visitor from Solaris. So why do they keep trying to hide their corresponding visitors? In particular, Kris has already told Snow about why Kris felt guilty about human-Rheya, and seems to have no problem telling Sartorius about it either. So why do they keep trying to hide the visitors away (as when they even turn off the video feed during a telephone call), and even keep trying to keep the visitors away even when there's serious danger to the structural integrity of the station (as when the door gets destroyed when the visitors are separated from their corresponding humans)?

It almost feels like there's an antisymmetric relation between the living humans and the visitors: The living humans try to move away from the visitors, and the visitors try to move towards the living humans.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a very long time since I read the book...

I think the humans are just feeling very unsettled by having their long dead loved ones come back.  Deep down they also know that these are not actually their loved ones.

Answer (score 1):

The visitors are some kind of attempt by Solaris to communicate with the human visitors.  It may have been an attempt to build a rapport with the humans; or it might have been meant to antagonize them; or it may be that Solaris is so alien that it is not really possible to attribute the creation of the visitors to any sort of conscious intention as we would understand it.  However, whyever they were created, the visitors were drawn from extremely emotionally important events in the four humans' pasts.  For Kelvin, the event was his lover's suicide, brought on by his leaving her.  It is suggested, although it can never really be confirmed, that each of the visitors represents the person's greatest memory of failure or regret.  In Kelvin's case, his visitor, Harey, was the other principal actor in the most traumatic event of his life.  The others may be recreations of principals from similarly unpleasant events in Snaut's, Giberian's, and Sartorius's pasts.

When faced with such an individual, it is quite natural that somebody might wish to keep their visitor away from others.  For Kelvin (and likely the others), the presence of the visitor is a reminder of what he considers his own most shameful behavior—driving the woman he loved to suicide.  She is an emblem from the lowest moments in his prior life.  He does not want her on display for other people to see; even if his crewmates don't know what she represents, having her out and about would be a public airing of Kelvin's shame.  He does not want the others wondering about what he had done to make Harey a representation of his greatest failure.

It is much easier for Snaut and Kelvin to talk about their visitors than to put them on display.  With talking, they can control the amount of information they give, and there is an extra layer of distance between the conversation and the visitor.  Kelvin certainly also develops a feeling that Harey is something that he needs to deal with himself:  to eliminate, to make amends, some something else; he is not sure quite what, but she is very clearly his problem.

Comment: A good answer-- I'd also add that the "shameful" visitors don't necessarily have to be real people from the person's past, they can be figments of imagination that are nevertheless the targets of obsessed thoughts.  The other scientists regard Kelvin's visitor, tragic as the story is, as "wholesome" compared to their own visitors.  They don't want to reveal an embodied aspect of their inner lives that they believed would remain forever hidden.